# Is there any way to return Flux<String> from spring REST end point to the web browser / front end application(i.e Angular 6)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I want to return Flux to the browser but when i hit the end point it gives me "406 not acceptable" error.

This is for a Apache tomcat server,running spring-boot 5, JAVA 8 .In STS(Spring Tool Suite) IDE.

```
@RestController
public class CloudFoundry {
    @GetMapping(value = "/LogApplication", produces =
            MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<String> logApplication() throws Throwable {
        return Flux.just("a", "b", "c", "d");

    }
}
```

when i hit the end point on localhost it should give me stream of string but instead it's giving me "406 not acceptable" error.

Answer (score 3):

`MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE` is used for Server-Sent-Events that need to be consumed appropriately.

This is what you need to have on front-end side:

```
// Declare an EventSource
const eventSource = new EventSource('http://server.url/LogApplication');
// Handler for events without an event type specified
eventSource.onmessage = (e) => {
  // Do something - event data etc will be in e.data
};
// Handler for events of type 'eventType' only eventSource.addEventListener('eventType', (e) => {
  // Do something - event data will be in e.data,
  // message will be of type 'eventType'
});
```

You can find a good explanation of Server-Sent-Events in the following blog post:
[A Look at Server-Sent Events](https://medium.com/conectric-networks/a-look-at-server-sent-events-54a77f8d6ff7)

Comment: 406 resource not found

Comment: Thanks it helped, it is a superb answer!